# how to download file from cpanel account to another cpanel account

Tags: linux, ssh, cpanel, wget, file-transfer

I trying to download a file from SSH of cpanel account that is hosted in another cpanel account, but this file can be downloaded only if I am logged in source cpanel account, I am connecting with SSH on WinCSP client, and run this command but return access denied.

This is the command line:

```
wget --user myusername --password mypassword http://www.domainname.com:2082/cpsess45379/getbackup/backup-domainname.com-2-23-2016.tar.gz
```

I am not a linux expert, can you help me telling me what is the problem?
this is the response from SSH:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally get archieve this, the way to log in cpanel and download the file is as follows:

wget -O /dev/null --http-user=##UserName## --http-password=##Password## http://www.domainname.com:2082/cpsess345308509/getbackup/backup-yourdomainbackup.com-2-23-2016.tar.gz --auth-no-challenge

With the --auth-no-challenge option I fixes the following issue:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Access Denied
Unknown authentication scheme.
Authorization failed.
```

According [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html), if this option is given, Wget will send Basic HTTP authentication information (plaintext username and password) for all requests, just like Wget 1.10.2 and prior did by default.

Comment: Why "-O /dev/null" ? 
Produces: Saving to: “/dev/null”

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give a try with the following command.

```
wget ftp://SERVER-IP/public_html/FILEPATH/FILENAME.tar.gz --ftp-user=cP-USER --ftp-pass=PASSWORD
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the file is not on ftp visible path, is in http://www.domainname.com:2082/cpses.....

Comment: What is the exact path of your backup file ?

Comment: http :// www.domainname.com:2082/cpsess45379/getbackup/backup-domainname.com-2-23-2016.tar.gz remove space in http

Answer (score -1):

wget -O test.zip --http-user=cpanelusername --http-password=cpanelpassword 'https://example.com:2083/cpsess3xxx/frontend/vvv/dailybackups/index.live.php?r=operations%2FdownloadResult&guid=14ba2e23-bf42-49c8-9cab-e0906c21b2b4' --auth-no-challenge (test.zip, is the filename you want to give to the downloaded file, enclose the URL in single quotes)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).